# Calculated values on a ASP.NET Core with Angular App

Tags: c#, sql-server, angular, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I'm currently developing an application on ASP.NET Core with Angular using Code First Migration and SQL Server. Now I have following "problem". I have data models with properties which always be refreshed on any change. The difficulty is that it is often calculated based on data of other models.

As an example:

I have these models (this is a little bit simplified):

```
public class Dinner {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Recipe> recipes {get; set; }

    public Dinner ()
    {
        Recipes= new Collection<Recipe>();
    }
}

public class Recipe {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Ingredient> ingredients {get; set; }

    public Recipe ()
    {
        Ingredients = new Collection<Ingredient>();
    }
}

public class Ingredient {

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
    public int RecipeId { get; set; }

    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }

}

public class Product {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<Price> Prices { get; set; }

    public Product()
    {
        Prices = new Collection<Price>();
    }
}

public class Price {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public decimal PricePerUnit { get; set; }

    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
}
```

I want to have

- a calculated property for ingredient (which is the price for that specific quantity based on the price for the product)
- a calculated property for recipe (the sum of all costs for all the ingredients)
- a calculated property for dinner (the sum of all used recipes)

My question is: For best practice where should I do add this property?

Currently I calculate these properties on the app component by calculation the property of the used interface during the onInit() process. But this requires for example to load all the data up to prices to calculate the sum property of Dinner.

My goal is to have these sum property as up-to-date as possible but I would like to have the calculation (if possible) on SQL Server so I do need to load less data. Does this approach make sense? And how can I achieve that goal?

Answer (score 1):

You can add your calculations as calculated columns in SQL Server. The calculated columns would be marked as such in the EF Core model. When EF retrieves a Dinner, for example, the calculated dinner cost column will be computed in SQL Server and returned to EF Core without needing to retrieve the related tables.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it out for my solution. If it works I will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the model, it looks like you have three tables in your DB.

Ideally, you should keep these calculated values stored in DB.

This means that, when you are inserting a record for a dinner, you would add ingredients first, then calculate the total of all ingredients and insert the recipe. Likewise, calculate the total of all recipes and use the same while adding a Dinner. ALL THIS CALCULATION SHOULD HAPPEN IDEALLY INSIDE THE CONTROLLER(INSIDE REPOSITORY TO BE PRECISE).

Then, whenever you read the Dinner, you get the calculated values from the DB into your API.

What say?

Comment: I will try to use calculated columns as mentioned in the other post first. But thank you for your feedback and ideas too.